# How to convert my EF Code-First to Database first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to convert my code-first project to Database first. Is there an automated way or should I just delete the entities and context code and create a model from the created database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to convert your code-first classes into database-first classes.  Creating the model from the database will create a whole new set of classes, regardless of the presence of your code-first classes.

However, you might not want to delete your code-first classes right away.  The entity framework database-first model creates partial classes for all of the entity objects.  If you have any business logic (anything besides the plain old properties) in your code-first classes, you can declare them as `partial`, remove the properties, and maintain the business logic.  Essentially, you're letting EF generate the properties in the *Designer.cs file, while you define the business logic in your .cs files.

Answer (score 3):

It appears Entity Framework Power Tools supports a feature called "Reverse Engineer Code-First". You can download it [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).